# Unzip php files

Tags: php, zip, extract

I'm trying to extract a zip file witch contains php files.

Taking for example a zip name 'test.zip' and inside, a zip.php file with this code:

```
<?php 
class php{

}  
?>
```

I've tried with two differents snippets to extract the zipe file:

```
$zip = zip_open ( 'test.zip' );
while($file = zip_read($zip)){
 $archivo = (zip_entry_name($file));    
 zip_entry_open($zip, $file);
 $contenido =  zip_entry_read($file);
 $fopen = fopen($archivo,'w+');
 fwrite($fopen, $contenido);    

}
```

---

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('test.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('./');
  $zip->close();
  echo 'ok!';
} else {
  echo 'ko!';
}
?>
```

---

But in both cases, the result is always the same:

```
<?php
class phpclass{
    function clase(){   

    }   
}
?>
```

The file extracted is twice longer, and has twice of empty breaklines than original.

Is there anyway to extract an identical copy of files contained in the zip file?

Comment: @Idris Undo that edit. You need to read the question first. He was describing the extra empty lines that he was getting from the unzip process and you have just removed tham all!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this:

```
$fopen = fopen($archivo,'w+');
```

... with this:

```
$fopen = fopen($archivo,'w+b');
```

The `b` flag stands for "binary" and disables line feed conversion. Flags are described in the [`fopen()` manual page](http://php.net/fopen).